# how to add to PATH variable in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, komodo, komodoedit

I'm going to try building a custom language extension for Komodo Edit.

In order to build an xpi file, I need to add something to the PATH variable.

I'm not really familiar with the command line, so I'm not 100% sure how to do this.

I started by created an empty .profile file in my user directory.

Can I add modify that in a text editor to do what I need to do?

Here's the instructions I'm trying to follow.
http://community.activestate.com/forum/introduction-building-komodo-extension

> Here is how packing up the Mako UDL into a Komodo extension works. Komodo includes a SDK in its install tree. On Linux and Windows this is found at "installdir/lib/sdk", and for a Mac it's found at "komodo.app/Contents/SharedSupport/sdk". That SDK includes a koext helper tool in the /lib/sdk/bin directory:
>   Put the SDK bin dir on your PATH and you should be able to run koext at the command line. Similar to tools like cvs or svn, these are tools with multiple sub-commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should be helpful

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/

```
export PATH=/ANYTHING_YOU_ARE_WORKIN_ON/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH export
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I ended up using. export PATH=$PATH:"/Applications/Komodo Edit.app/Contents/SharedSupport/sdk/bin"